# Random strings with dictionaries based on class variable

Tags: swift

I am practicing swift by creating a randomly generated text adventure, if you could call it that.

`positionArr` is an 2D Array containing instances of the class `rooms`, where each cell is filled with the randomly generated `room` with the properties of `temperature` and `enteredBefore`, which tracks whether you have been in the room or not.  `currentRow`/`currentCollum` keep track of which room you are in. With he `func returnText()` below I am hoping to randomly generate text to output based on the `roomReference`, which is your current room

```
func returnText()
{

    var roomReference = positionArr[currentRow][currentCollum]

        var tempature =
        [
            true: ["It's cold Outside","it's warm"],
            false: ["It's warm Outside", "it's cold"]
        ]

        var entered =
        [
            true: ["You have been here before","This isn't the first time you have been here before"],
            false: ["This room seems new","This is the first time you have been here"]
        ]
```

Using dictionaries `temperature` and `entered` with the variables I am looking to randomly select the correct properties, if you enter a cold room, i.e.. less than 0 it will be `true` and select a 'cold' phrase.

```
    //This is pseudo of what I am trying to do

    var text1 = temperature[roomReference.temperature <= 0].getRandom()

   //if room tempature is less than zero, it is TRUE, therfore grabbing cold text from the dictionary

    var text2:String = entered[roomReference.enteredBefore].getRandom()
```

I want to make `text1` the correct temperature phrase and `text2` the correct phrase based on whether you have entered a room. This isn't really a bug or an error, as I just don't know how to do this. I am in high school and am struggling and any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a more complicated question, and there are countless reasonable implementations.  To answer a first step, accessing a random member of an array:

```
myArray[random() % myArray.count]
```

That should give you a reasonably random string back.